# Preposition for available time slot

Tags: prepositions, sentence

I'm trying to find available time among group members for my talk.

I wrote:

*Are you available at the following time slots for my talk?*

The online grammar checker (grammarly) tells me that I should replace **at** with **for**.

I feel the suggestion may not be a good idea because it will end up with two **for** in the sentence.

What is the proper preposition for ** available time slot**? Or

Is there a better way to rephrase the sentence?

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: Except when giving precise times, 'available for' is the normal choice. You can separate the _for_'s to what must be considered an acceptable distance by even the most fussy: 'Are you available for any of the following time slots for my talk?'